# How to make declare in a Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to put below declare in a shell script: proxy_set

```
declare -x https_proxy="https://192.168.220.4:8080/"
```

And then I execute it like below.

```
$ ./proxy_set
```

But "export" shows nothing happened.

And in another way if I execute it like this:

```
$ source proxy_set
```

Then "export" shows it works!

My question is how can I make it work without additional "source" cmd?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Setting variables in the environment only affects the environment of that shell and any future children it spawns; there's no way to affect the parent shell.  When you run it without the `source` (or `.`), a brand new shell is started up, then the variable is set in that shell's environment, and then that shell exits, taking its environment with it.

The `source` reads the commands and executes them within the current shell as if you had typed them.

So if you want to set environment variables in a script, you have to `source` it.  Alternatively, you can have a command generate shell commands as output instead of running them, and then the parent can evaluate the output of the command.  Things like `ssh-agent` use this approach.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination! It is quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding:

```
export https_proxy="https://192.168.220.4:8080/"
```

Then execute your script normally.